# Lenovo Yoga 3 1470 Screen Dimmed

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, intel-graphics

Info:

Brand **Lenovo**
Product Line **Lenovo Yoga 3 1470**
Model **80JH**
Graphics Processor **Intel HD Graphics 5500**
Operating System **Windows 10 x64**

My Lenovo Yoga 3 suddenly has a dimmed screen. First I've tried connecting it using the micro HDMI to my other screen and it's fine. I can also see the picture on the Lenovo screen but barely, the touch functionality works perfectly.

Things I've tried:

Installed, uninstalled **Intel HD** drivers (latest and old) - nothing changed
Used the **Microsoft Basic Display Adapter** - no luck
Changed the registry values
Removed the battery then powered the Yoga
Restarted in **Safe Mode**
Disable the **Auto brightness** in **Power Management** and in **Intel HD**
Disable the **Adaptive Brightness**

It seems that the **Brightness control** has no affect but if i use the **Night display mode** the screen color changes.

[Lenovo Yoga 3 Hardware Manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/lenovo_yoga_3_14_hmm_201502.pdf)
[Lenovo Yoga 3 Service Videos](https://www.lenovoservicetraining.com/showcase?sid=448&key=TGVuZw==)
[Lenovo Yoga 3 Repair Instructions](https://www.ifixit.com/Device/Lenovo_Yoga_3_Pro)

**Update**

I've used the [Warranty Upgrade Registration](https://support.lenovo.com/hr/en/warrantylookup/warrantyupgraderegistration) as the warranty start or end date was wrong using [warranty lookup tool](http://support.lenovo.com/hr/en/warrantylookup). After that I've used my warranty and sent the device to a [service provider](https://support.lenovo.com/hr/en/serviceprovider).

Turns out the issue was loose cables and the screen was fine.

Comment: Seems like the backlight to the monitor may be faulty.  Is the machine under warranty?

Comment: @CheesusCrust It's not, otherwise I would have send it already as this happened with no particular reason.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the backlight in your LCD screen has died, which would explain why you still get a picture even though it is barely visible.

The best thing I can recommend is to replace the screen unfortunately.

**Link to the Screen on Amazon:**
http://a.co/6niNU6h

**Link to How-To:**
https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/Lenovo+Yoga+3+Pro+Display+Assembly+Replacement/52401

If you are not familiar or comfortable with taking your machine apart yourself, I would highly recommend you bring it somewhere to be replaced.  Perhaps you can also get a second opinion while you are there just to be sure

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I'm fine with taking the laptop apart and will do it if needed. Will update this when I get the issue resolved. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

motherboard problem. change the new motherboard. this caused because your laptop is overheating. it is not a software problem but hardware problem. you got extremely overheated problem that causing this to happen in the first place.

Comment: The laptop never overheated.